# Prove that $M$ is a complex.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $f:(A,d) \rightarrow (A^{'},d^{'})$ be a chain map. For each $n$ define $$M_{n}=A_{n-1} \oplus A^{'}_n$$
and $\Delta_{n} :M_{n} \rightarrow M_{n-1}$ by 
$$\Delta_{n}:(a_{n-1},a_{n}^{'}) \rightarrow (-d_{n-1}a_{n-1},d^{'}a^{'}+f_{n-1}a_{n-1}).$$

Prove that $(M,\Delta)$ as just defined is a complex.

this will be great if you give me some hint or Idea,thanks a lot.

Comment: **Hint:**  Check that $\Delta_{n-1} \circ \Delta_n = 0$.

Comment: This is called the *mapping cone*.  See, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cone_(homological_algebra)

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to write up your calculation as an answer and select the answer so that the question doesn't remain open—you know, for posterity.

Comment: All hints above are very good. Here are my 2 cents for calculations: to check that $\Delta_{n-1}\circ\Delta_n =0$ remember that $f$ commutes with $d$ and $d'$ as it is a chain complex map and $d^2=(d')^2=0$, by definition.